# How to do row movement in case of subpartitioning in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

---

How to do the row movement in case of update on subpartition key in postgres .
Consider  T is master table with seq_id as Partition key.
t1 and t2 are the partion table.
I have done the range subpartitiong on t1 and t2 with date/month as subpartition key.

T -> t1->t1_may ,
     t1->t1_june

T -> t2->t2_may ,
       t2->t2_june

Now how will i move the row from t2_june to t1_june in case I update the row in subpartition.

Comment: use keyword `ONLY` ?.. Please give us idea of structure and data sample

Comment: She wants to have rows automatically moved to a different partition when the partitioning key is modified.

Comment: aaah. probably. too bad then